# Don’t seem too forward / Don’t seem overly friendly

Tags: difference, politeness, sentence-choice

Let’s suppose someone is behaving in a very impolite and perhaps rude way with you and you dislike his manners toward yourself. In such a condition, do the following sentences mean the same and can they be used under these circumstances?

> Don’t seem too forward. 
>   Don’t seem overly friendly.

I wonder if you clarify the meaning of each one.

Comment: Really, neither fit the situation you describe.

Comment: You ask questions quite frequently. Why don't you format them? It'll be helpful for others to read and answer. Every time it's difficult to simply edit the question for formatting.

Comment: Simply click on 'edited' above my photo! Observe the changes, imply now on!

Comment: @boatseller do they make any sense in English at all?

Comment: No need to click on anything. Simply put ('>') sign and see the changes down there, live! Recheck my edit.

Comment: LOL, for the very first time I tried to answer the way natives have been advising me. And I'm wrong! :P Yeah, you also gave me a hint that I may not answer your questions as I'm a non-native speaker. Thanks for calling me 'friend!' though. I deleted my answer so it does not mislead anyone here.

Comment: @A-friend I think you missed out some important aspects of the scenario you described. I believe the choice of words would depend on the relationship between you and that person (an 8yo child, your friend, or your boss?), the occasion, and how you'd like to response (directly, openly, equally impolite, politely, or sarcastically?). There are plenty of possible phrases, but only you will know exactly what you would use in each specific circumstance.

Comment: This question needs work in order for it to be a good question. Your asking for *advice* on how to handle a very generic impolite encounter, and then only giving two choices.  There's no clear question/answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your examples:

> Don’t seem too forward. 
>   Don’t seem overly friendly.

*seem* is not a good verb to use here, as it describes how things appear or the impression you get, not the state or actions of the other person.

When responding to the other person, it would be better to say, for example:

> Don’t *be* too forward.
>   Don’t *act* overly friendly.

Usages of *seem* could be:

> He seems too forward. 
>   They don't seem overly friendly.

Comment: Wow. Thanks @user3169. :) Do the following sentences mean the same thing for this scenario of mine?
 - Don't get fresh with me.
- Don't get free and easy with me.
- Don’t be too forward.
- Don’t act overly friendly.

Comment: @A-friend *free and easy* is more a state than an action, so you would rather say "Don't be free and easy with me." The other three are OK.

Comment: So I will learn them as identical concepts. Thank you very much @user3169. ;)

Comment: according to Longman Dictionary's definition, "getting fresh with somebody" is an old-fashioned phrase. Is it right or it is in common use yet?

Comment: 1. No, they don't mean the same thing.  2. "getting fresh" is not used very often but is still a polite way of referring to sexual advances.

Comment: Is it used only for sexual issues?

Comment: @A-friend As a set phrase, yes. Primarily used amongst young people. For example if you went on a date and the guy tried to touch the girl or make advances of a sexual nature, that would be considered "getting fresh". She might say "Are you trying to get fresh with me?.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, these two sentences:

> Don’t seem too forward.
>
> Don’t seem overly friendly.

are in the Imperative.  So, you telling someone to not be "too forward" or "overly friendly."  They're perfectly fine if you're giving someone advice on how behave with someone else.

However, "too forward" and "overly friendly" are just not a good match for "someone is behaving in a very impolite and perhaps rude way with you and you dislike his manners".  In fact, "overly friendly" is the opposite.

The two do not mean the same thing and are not interchangeable but the attitudes they describe have many overlapping characteristics.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just I wonder if you tell me what does "Don't be too forward" mean? Does it mean do not speak too openly and don't mention (for example) sexual jokes and so on this easily and this freely?

Comment: Sure, that all works, but you can certainly be too forward without being saucy :).